# How to find the length of an array and sum of an array and then sumproduct of two diff arrays in cplex IBM ilog?

Tags: python, arrays, cplex, opl, ibm-ilog-opl

I have

```
int a ;
int b ; 
int c ;
range m= 1..a;
range n= 1..b;
range o= 1..c;
int s[m]=[11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
int q[m][o]=[[4,5,0,2],[3,2,1,0],[0,1,4,5],[3,2,0,1],[2,1,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[3,4,2,0],[5,0,3,1],[0,4,3,3],[4,0,4,1]];
a=length(s);
b= sum(i in m) s[i];
c=length(q[m]);
int d[o]
forall(k in o)
   int d[k]= sum(i in m) (s[i]*q[i][k]);
```

The statements for a,b,c,d are not correct. I dont want to initialise diectly for a,b,c,d, and I need to store `a` as length of s[m] which is 10, `b` as sum of s[m] which is 20, `c` as length of one D element of q[m][o] which is 4, and `d[k]` for as sumproduct of s and q for each k which is 68,72,22,36 respectively. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=10 ;
 
int c=4 ;
range m= 1..a;

range o= 1..c;
int s[m]=[11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
int q[m][o]=[[4,5,0,2],[3,2,1,0],[0,1,4,5],[3,2,0,1],[2,1,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[3,4,2,0],[5,0,3,1],[0,4,3,3],[4,0,4,1]];
//a=length(s);
int b= sum(i in m) s[i];
//c=length(q[m]);
int d[k in o]=sum(i in m) (s[i]*q[i][k]);
execute
{
  writeln("d=",d);
}
```

works fine and gives

```
d= [68 72 22 36]
```